# Google maps not working IE11 (sharepoint 2010)

Tags: google-maps, sharepoint-2010, javascript-objects

I have a code to show Google Maps in my list on Sharepoint 2010. Code plot list items in the map. Work great with Edge and Chrome, but on IE not.

In IE console error on this line (object doesn't support this action (error 445))

**var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(defaultLatitude,defaultLongitude);**

```
//build map
  $('#'+idOfMapDiv).css({"width":mapWidth, "height":mapHeight});    
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(defaultLatitude,defaultLongitude);
  var myOptions = {
      zoom: 6,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var gmMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(idOfMapDiv), myOptions);
  var gmBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  var gmGeocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

  var jQuerySelect_GetListRowByAttributeCTXName;
  if(isSharePoint2010)
  {
    jQuerySelect_GetListRowByAttributeCTXName = jQuerySelect_2010_GetListRowByAttributeCTXName;
  }
  else
  {
    jQuerySelect_GetListRowByAttributeCTXName = jQuerySelect_2007_GetListRowByAttributeCTXName;
  }
```

Full code on Sharepoint:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=MY KEY" type="text/javascript"></script><script type="text/javascript">

/* ***************************************************** 
   AND NOW SOME VARIABLES YOU MAY WANT TO CHANGE.
   ***************************************************** */
var mapWidth = "1725px";     //the width of the map
var mapHeight = "400px";    //the height of the map

//if true the coordinates (latitude, longitude) will be used
//if false the addresses (street, zip, city, country) will be used
var useCoordinates = true;

//if true the map will not be shown by default 
//if false the map will be shown by default
var hideMapUntilClick = false;

//if 0 absolutely no warning- and error-alerts will be written to a log-div
//if 1 the warning- and error-alerts will be written to a log-div
//if 2 the warning- and error-alerts will be alerted via javascript-alert
var showWarningAndErrorAlerts = 1;

//the internal-names of list-columns (not the display-name!)
var colLinkTitleInternalName = "ows_Nome_x0020_Instala_x00e7__x00e3_";     //will be used as the title of the geo-markers
var colLongitudeInternalName = "ows_Longitude";     //useCoordinates == true
var colLatitudeInternalName = "ows_Latitude";       //useCoordinates == true
var colStreetInternalName = "WorkAddress";        //useCoordinates == false
var colStreetDisplayName = "Endereço";             //useCoordinates == false
var colZipInternalName = "WorkZip";                 //useCoordinates == false
var colCityInternalName = "WorkCity";                //useCoordinates == false
var colCountryInternalName = "WorkCountry";            //useCoordinates == false
var defaultCountryValue = "Brazil";                //the default country which will be used if no country-name will be found in the list-column

//default position (Germany: 51.165691,10.451526) > used if no markers will be set to the map
var defaultLatitude = -15.77972;
var defaultLongitude = -47.92972;

//some language-specific messages
var resxGoogleMapsLink = "Google-Map";  //the name of new menu-point in the menu-toolbar of the sharepoint-list
var resxGoogleMapsLinkTitle = "Menu: Show or hide Google-Map";  //the title which will be visible while hovering
var resxAlertsMessageText = resxGoogleMapsLink+": There are # hints!";   //the hint which will be visible if configuration warnings or errors occured.
var resxAlertsMessageTextTitle = "Click here to show or hide the hints!";    //the title which will be visible while hovering

/* *******************************************************************
   NOW DO NOT CHANGE ANYTHING IF YOU ARE NOT FAMILIAR WITH JAVASCRIPT!
   ******************************************************************* */
var isSharePoint2010 = true;
var hasMapBeenLoadedInitially = false;

var idOfMapDiv = "divGoogleMapForSharePointList";
var idOfCustomLogDiv = "divCustomLog";
var idOfCustomLogOverview = "divCustomLogOverview";

var noOfCustomLogEntries = 0;
var noOfMaxGeocodingRequest = 10;

//the attribute-name of the column "id" > will be used for a) finding the id of a certain row and b) for building the ajax-request-url
var colID = "ID";

//now some templates for jquery-selects
var jQuerySelect_2007_GetListRowByAttributeCTXName = "table[CTXName]";
var jQuerySelect_2010_GetListRowByAttributeCTXName = "div[CTXName]";

function InitializeGoogleMapForSharePointList()
{
  BuildGoogleMapCustomLogForSharePointList();

  if(!DoPreCheckForInitializationOfGooglemapsForSharePointList())
  {
    //pre-check not successfully done > abort now!    
    customAlert("The Pre-Check has not been successfully! > Abort now.");    
    return;
  }

  DoSchemaCheckAndBuildGoogleMapIconForSharePointList();  
}

function DoSchemaCheckAndBuildGoogleMapIconForSharePointList()
{
  //get the schema-data for the list
  $.get(BuildAjaxRequestUrlForSharePointListSchemaOnly(), {}, function (xml) 
  {    
    //find all necessary internal-field-names
    var arrNeccessaryFields = new Array();
    arrNeccessaryFields.push(colLinkTitleInternalName);
    if(useCoordinates)
    {
      arrNeccessaryFields.push(colLatitudeInternalName);
      arrNeccessaryFields.push(colLongitudeInternalName);
    }
    else
    {
      arrNeccessaryFields.push(colStreetInternalName);
      arrNeccessaryFields.push(colZipInternalName);
      arrNeccessaryFields.push(colCityInternalName);
      arrNeccessaryFields.push(colCountryInternalName);
    }

    //check all neccessary internal-field-names
    var foundAllNeccessaryFields = true;
    for(i=0;i<arrNeccessaryFields.length;i++)
    { 
      //getting <xml><s:Schema><s:ElementType><s:AttributeType name="[internal-field-name]">
      var xmlQuery = 'xml > *:first > *:first > *[name='+arrNeccessaryFields[i]+']';
      if($(xmlQuery, xml).length<1)
      {
        foundAllNeccessaryFields = false;
        customAlert("Schema-Check failed for internal-field-name '"+arrNeccessaryFields[i]+"'. The field is not available in this list.");
      }      
    }

    //check if the neccessary fields have been found
    if(foundAllNeccessaryFields)
    {
      BuildGoogleMapIconForSharePointList();
    }    
    else
    {
      var ajaxRequestLinkTag = '<a href="'+BuildAjaxRequestUrlForSharePointListSchemaOnly()+'" target="_blank" title="Click here to call the ajax-request for this SharePoint-List-Schema manually.">ajax-request for list-schema</a>';
      customAlert("Hint: You can get the internal names of the columns by calling the "+ajaxRequestLinkTag+" for the current sharepoint-list manually.");
      customAlert("Schema-Check failed. Abort now!");
    }
  });
}

function DoPreCheckForInitializationOfGooglemapsForSharePointList()
{
  //check if this is SharePoint2010 or not 
  //if it is not 2010 it is assumed that it is 2007
  if(typeof(_fV4UI)!='undefined')
  {
    //the checked javascript-variable exists only in 2010
    isSharePoint2010 = true;    
  }
  else
  {
    isSharePoint2010 = false;    
  }

  //for the first shot: support only one table 
  //for further version we could support more tables (table[class=ms-listviewtable].length>1)
  var noOfListViews = $("table[class=ms-listviewtable]").length;
  if(noOfListViews==0)
  {    
    //no list-view exists > there is no need to show google-maps
    customAlert("There is no list-view available on this site. > No need to show google-maps. > Abort now.");
    return false;
  }
  else if(noOfListViews>1)
  {    
    //there are more than one list-view > this is not supported at the moment
    customAlert("There are more than one list-views on the site. This is not supported at the moment. > Abort now!");
    return false;
  }

  //check if multi-lookup exists
  if($("table[FieldType=LookupMulti]").length>0)
  {    
    //If there are columns in the list-view which are of type multi-lookup the ajax-call (via owssrv.dll) will return zero results. 
    var multiMsg = "Multi-lookup exists! Please remove the mulit-lookup-column or use another view (otherwise the ajax-request will receive an empty result). > Abort now!";

    multiMsg += "\n\nColumns which are of type multi-lookup are (the display-name will be shown):";

    $("table[FieldType=LookupMulti]").each(function(){
      var displayName = $(this).attr("displayName");
      multiMsg += "\n- "+displayName;
    });    

    customAlert(multiMsg);
    return false;
  }

  //check if javascript-variable exists > we need ctx to get the id of the sharepoint-list
  if(ctx==null)
  {
    //this javascript-variable is essential for getting the list-id and the list-view-id.
    customAlert("The javascript-variable 'ctx' does not exist within the html-dom. > Abort now!");
    return false;
  }

  //all checks passed - return true
  return true;
}

function BuildGoogleMapCustomLogForSharePointList()
{
  if(showWarningAndErrorAlerts!=1)
  {
    return;
  }

  var divCustomLogOverview = '<div title="'+resxAlertsMessageTextTitle+'" onclick="ToggleCustomLog();" id="'+idOfCustomLogOverview+'" style="margin: 10px; cursor: pointer; color: red; display: none;"></div>';
  $("table.ms-menutoolbar").parent().append(divCustomLogOverview);

  var divCustomLog = '<div id="'+idOfCustomLogDiv+'" style="margin: 10px; display: none;"></div>';
  $("table.ms-menutoolbar").parent().append(divCustomLog);
}

function ToggleCustomLog()
{
  //show or hide
  $("#"+idOfCustomLogDiv).toggle();
}

function ToggleGoogleMapDiv()
{
  //check if the map will be called for the first time  
  if(!hasMapBeenLoadedInitially)
  { 
    ShowGoogleMapForSharePointList();
  }

  //show or hide
  $("#"+idOfMapDiv).toggle();
}

function BuildGoogleMapIconForSharePointList()
{
  //searching for the correct position in the menu-toolbar (ms-menutoolbar)
  $("td.ms-toolbar").each(function(j){
    if($(this).attr("width")=="99%")
    {
      //insert a new menu-item before the found placeholder
      //var newMenuItem = '</internal-name-of-column><td class="ms-separator">';
      var newMenuItem = '<td class="ms-separator">';
      newMenuItem += '<img src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif" alt=""/>';
      newMenuItem += '</td>';
      newMenuItem += '<td nowrap="true" class="ms-toolbar">';
      newMenuItem += '<span title="'+resxGoogleMapsLinkTitle+'">';
      newMenuItem += '<div nowrap="nowrap" hoverinactive="ms-menubuttoninactivehover" hoveractive="ms-menubuttonactivehover" onmouseover="MMU_PopMenuIfShowing(this);MMU_EcbTableMouseOverOut(this, true)" class="ms-menubuttoninactivehover">';
      newMenuItem += '<a onclick="javascript:ToggleGoogleMapDiv();return false;" href="#" style="cursor: pointer; white-space: nowrap;">'+resxGoogleMapsLink+'</a>';
      newMenuItem += '</div>';
      newMenuItem += '</span>';
      newMenuItem += '</td>';
      $(this).before(newMenuItem);
    }
  });

  //adding map-canvas as div-tag to the dom
  var divMapCanvas = '<div id="'+idOfMapDiv+'" style="margin: 10px; display: none;"></div>';
  $("table.ms-menutoolbar").parent().before(divMapCanvas);

  //check if the map should be shown as soon as possible or if it should be hidden until the user clicked the new menu-point
  if(!hideMapUntilClick)
  {    
    ToggleGoogleMapDiv();
  }
}

//gets the complete list-schema and one row with all its values (not filtered by the current used view)
function BuildAjaxRequestUrlForSharePointListByID_Template()
{
  if(ctx!=null)
  {
    //build the url of the ajax-request
    return ctx.HttpRoot+'/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?XMLDATA=1&List=' + ctx.listName + '&Query=*&FilterField1='+colID+'&FilterValue1=';
  }
}

//gets the list-schema and no rows
function BuildAjaxRequestUrlForSharePointListSchemaOnly()
{
  //build the url of the ajax-request
  return BuildAjaxRequestUrlForSharePointListByID_Template()+'-1';  
}

function ShowGoogleMapForSharePointList()
{ 
  //build the url of the ajax-request
  var urlTemplate = BuildAjaxRequestUrlForSharePointListByID_Template();

  //build map
  $('#'+idOfMapDiv).css({"width":mapWidth, "height":mapHeight});    
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(defaultLatitude,defaultLongitude);
  var myOptions = {
      zoom: 6,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var gmMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(idOfMapDiv), myOptions);
  var gmBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  var gmGeocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

  var jQuerySelect_GetListRowByAttributeCTXName;
  if(isSharePoint2010)
  {
    jQuerySelect_GetListRowByAttributeCTXName = jQuerySelect_2010_GetListRowByAttributeCTXName;
  }
  else
  {
    jQuerySelect_GetListRowByAttributeCTXName = jQuerySelect_2007_GetListRowByAttributeCTXName;
  }

  //check if the number of geocodings will exceed the max-number
  if(!useCoordinates && $(jQuerySelect_GetListRowByAttributeCTXName).length > noOfMaxGeocodingRequest)
  { 
    var linkToStatusCodes = '<a title="Statuscodes of geocoding-responses from Google-Maps" target="_blank" href="http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#GeocodingStatusCodes">OVER_QUERY_LIMIT-Status</a>';
    var tooManyMsg = "Hint: In the current view of the SharePoint-List there are more than "+noOfMaxGeocodingRequest+" list-entries. ";
    tooManyMsg += "This will result in an "+linkToStatusCodes+" by Google-Maps (and not all markers will be shown on the map). > You have 2 options: ";
    tooManyMsg += "a) Change your view to get no more than "+noOfMaxGeocodingRequest+" list-entries or ";
    tooManyMsg += "b) use the coordinates (longitude, latitude) of the addresses (they will be shown on the map).";
    customAlert(tooManyMsg);  
  }

  //get each row from list-view which is shown at the moment
  $(jQuerySelect_GetListRowByAttributeCTXName).each(function(j)
  {
    var lat, lng, gmLatLng, gmMarker, title, customUrl, street, city, country;
    var idOfListItem = $(this).attr(colID);
    if(isSharePoint2010)
    {
        var linkToListItem = '<table height="auto" width="calcWidthpx"><tr class="ms-alternating ms-itmhover"><td height="100%" class="ms-vb-title" onmouseover="OnChildItem(this)">';  
        linkToListItem += $(this).parent().html();
        linkToListItem += '</td></tr></table><span style="font-size:72pt;"></br></span>';
    }
    else
    {
        linkToListItem = $(this).parent().html();
        linkToListItem = linkToListItem.replace(/100%/g, "auto");   //exchange tag-attributes for width and height
    }  

    //build url for the ajax-request which reads all data for a certain row (for the current list-view)
    customUrl = urlTemplate+idOfListItem; 

    //get the data for the row
    $.get(customUrl, {}, function (xml) 
    {    
      $('xml > *:last > *', xml).each(function (i) 
      {
        //get some data from the xml-response
        title = $(this).attr(colLinkTitleInternalName);
        if(isSharePoint2010)
        { 
        var titleLength= title.length+185;
        linkToListItem = linkToListItem.replace('calcWidth', titleLength);
        }
        if(useCoordinates)
        {
          //getting coordinates
          lat = $(this).attr(colLatitudeInternalName);
          lng = $(this).attr(colLongitudeInternalName);

          if(typeof(lat)!='undefined' && typeof(lng)!='undefined')
          {
            gmLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
            msgForInfoWindow = linkToListItem;            //you may add more information-text here
            SetMarkerForGoogleMapForSharePointList(gmLatLng, gmMap, gmBounds, title, msgForInfoWindow);
          }        
          else
          {
            customAlert(title +" has undefined lat+lng. > Do not add marker on map.");
          }
        }
        else
        {
          //getting address
          street = $(this).attr(colStreetInternalName);
          zip = $(this).attr(colZipInternalName);
          city = $(this).attr(colCityInternalName);
          country = $(this).attr(colCountryInternalName);   

          //checking received values
          if(typeof(street)=='undefined') street = "";  //optional 
          if(typeof(zip)=='undefined') zip = "";        //optional
          if(typeof(city)=='undefined') 
          {
            customAlert("The ajax-response got no city for '"+title+"'. > Do not add marker on map.");
            return;
          }
          if(typeof(country)=='undefined') country = defaultCountryValue;

          address = street+","+zip+","+city+","+country;

          //getting coordinates
          gmGeocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {            
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) 
            {
              if(results.length==0)
              {
                customAlert("Geocoding: There are no results for address '"+results[0].formatted_address+"'! Expected exactly one result. > Do not show any marker on map for this address.");
              }
              else if(results.length>1)
              {
                var msg = "Geocoding: There are too many ("+results.length+") results for given address! Expected exactly one result. > Do not show any marker on map for this address.\n\nFound addresses:\n";
                for(i=0;i<results.length;i++)
                {
                  var c = i+1;
                  msg += "\n"+c+": "+results[i].formatted_address;
                }
                customAlert(msg);
              }
              else
              {
                gmLatLng = results[0].geometry.location;
                var msgForInfoWindow = linkToListItem+"<br>";
                msgForInfoWindow += "<span style='font-size:0.8em;'>Koordinaten (Lat, Lon): "+gmLatLng+"<br>Adresse: "+results[0].formatted_address+"</span>";
                SetMarkerForGoogleMapForSharePointList(gmLatLng, gmMap, gmBounds, title, msgForInfoWindow);
              }
            }
            else
            {
              customAlert("Geocode for address '"+address+"' was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
            }
          });          
        }

      });     
    });    
  });

  hasMapBeenLoadedInitially = true;
}

function SetMarkerForGoogleMapForSharePointList(gmLatLng, gmMap, gmBounds, title, contentForInfoWindow)
{
  var gmMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: gmLatLng,
    map: gmMap,
    title: title,
    zIndex: 0
  });
  gmBounds.extend(gmLatLng);
  gmMap.setCenter(gmBounds.getCenter());
  gmMap.fitBounds(gmBounds);

  if(contentForInfoWindow!=null && contentForInfoWindow!="")
  {
    var gmInfowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: contentForInfoWindow
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(gmMarker, 'click', function() {
         gmInfowindow.open(gmMap,gmMarker); 
    });
  }
}

function customAlert(msg)
{
  if(msg==null || msg=="")
  {
    return;
  }
  else
  {
    var now = new Date();
    msg = now.getHours()+":"+now.getMinutes()+":"+now.getSeconds()+": "+msg;
  }

  if(showWarningAndErrorAlerts==0)
  {
    //do nothing
  }
  else if(showWarningAndErrorAlerts==1)
  {
    //do log in log-div
    msg = msg.replace(/\n/g, "<br/>");
    msg += "<br/><br/>";
    $("#"+idOfCustomLogDiv).append(msg);

    noOfCustomLogEntries++;
    $("#"+idOfCustomLogOverview).show();
    var overviewText = resxAlertsMessageText.replace(/#/g, noOfCustomLogEntries);
    $("#"+idOfCustomLogOverview).text(overviewText);    

  }
  else if(showWarningAndErrorAlerts==2)
  {
    //do alert via javascript-alert
    alert(msg);
  }
  else
  {
    //unsupported
  }
}

//call initialization after the dom has been loaded completely > so it does not matter where this piece of javascript will be inserted in the dom
$(document).ready(InitializeGoogleMapForSharePointList);</script>
```

Result in Chrome e Edge:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7BAe.jpg)

Comment: Do you have something like this in your page? "<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">"

Comment: Works! Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to put an answer to this question, adding the `meta` tag of `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">` would solve the issue.